# How to create and configure an .apk file for deploy my android app to avd emulator?

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, apk, android-virtual-device

I want to deploy an android app to an android virtual device.
I did all the java, sdk , gradle installation, and have my avd running perfectly. Now I want to create and configure an app so, i created a new folder and did `gradle init` to initialize a new project

```
Select type of project to generate:
  1: basic
  2: application
  3: library
  4: Gradle plugin
Enter selection (default: basic) [1..4] 2

Select implementation language:
  1: C++
  2: Groovy
  3: Java
  4: Kotlin
  5: Scala
  6: Swift
Enter selection (default: Java) [1..6] 3

Generate multiple subprojects for application? (default: no) [yes, no] 
Select build script DSL:
  1: Kotlin
  2: Groovy
Enter selection (default: Kotlin) [1..2] 1
```

root/`settings.gradle`

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * The settings file is used to specify which projects to include in your build.
 * For more detailed information on multi-project builds, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/building_swift_projects.html in the Gradle documentation.
 */

rootProject.name = "app"
include (":app")
```

Then i configured my root/`build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the root/app/`build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    namespace 'com.name.myapplication'
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.karl.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

this is my `gradle-wrapper.properties` config:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2.1-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

(https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/10/basic-android-without-an-ide i followed this)
and when I run `./gradlew build` I have multiple errors even though I am solving them, i would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to configure everything correctly.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The common command for Android projects gradle is `./gradlew assembleRelease` and `./gradlew assembleDebug`. Nate that for AGP 8.2.1 you should use Java 17. I would recommend to excatly use that version not lower and not higher.

Comment: @Robert thanks! I'm already using java 17. I made some changes and the error changed to `Package R does not exist in setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`